# rails new を実行した際に、rails aborted ！というエラーが出て解決できません。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile

rails new を実行した際に、下記のエラーが表示されます

```
rails aborted!
TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound: tzinfo-data is not present. Please add gem 'tzinfo-data' to your Gemfile and run bundle install
C:/Users/usera/envrionment/sample_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'

Caused by:
TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDirectoryNotFound: None of the paths included in TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDataSource.search_path are valid zoneinfo directories.
C:/Users/usera/envrionment/sample_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => app:template => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
       rails  turbo:install stimulus:install
You must either be running with node (package.json) or importmap-rails (config/importmap.rb) to use this gem.
You must either be running with node (package.json) or importmap-rails (config/importmap.rb) to use this gem.
```

Gemfileに'gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]'を加えて、bundle installを実行したのですが、rails serverを実行した際に、下記のエラーが表示され原因が何なのかわかりません。

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.0.2.2 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:159:in `rescue in create_default_data_source': tzinfo-data is not present. Please add gem 'tzinfo-data' to your Gemfile and run bundle install (TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound)
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:156:in `create_default_data_source'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:55:in `block in get'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:54:in `synchronize'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:54:in `get'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.2/lib/active_support/railtie.rb:88:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Users/kazuk/envrionment/sample_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:42:in `require_relative'
        from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:76:in `log_to_stdout'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:36:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:143:in `block in perform'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_sources/zoneinfo_data_source.rb:232:in `initialize': None of the paths included in TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDataSource.search_path are valid zoneinfo directories. (TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDirectoryNotFound)
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:157:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:157:in `create_default_data_source'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:55:in `block in get'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:54:in `synchronize'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:54:in `get'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.2/lib/active_support/railtie.rb:88:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Users/kazuk/envrionment/sample_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:42:in `require_relative'
        from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:76:in `log_to_stdout'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:36:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:143:in `block in perform'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

もし何かご存じであれば教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　パッと見 Windows 環境のようですが、どのような環境のもとで動かしてらっしゃるのか、OS や Ruby、ターミナルなどなどの情報を分かる限り、質問文を [edit] して追記いただけないでしょうか。問題を再現して原因を切り分けるのに役立ちます。

Comment: 現在質問者さん本人と思われる方から編集提案がされていますが、本来質問者自身であれば質問は自由に編集できます。もしアカウン‌​‌​トが2つに分かれてしまった場合は、[ア‌​カウ‌​ントのマージ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)を行ってください。

Answer (score 0):

[Ruby Instnaller](https://rubyinstaller.org/)の64bit最新版 3.1.1-1 (x64) を使用しているという前提でお話しします。もし、違っている場合は、この回答は無視してください。

---

Ruby InstallerはMSYS2の開発環境を用いてRubyをビルドします。以前は、MSYS2にmingw32とmingw64の二つの開発環境しか用意されていませんでしたが、現在はclang32、clang64、ucrt64の三つの開発環境が追加されました。clangはMingw-w64 GCCの代わりにClangを用いる物ですが、ucrt64はmingw32やmingw64と同じくMingw-w64 GCCを用います。そのような経緯もあって、Ruby Istallerの64bit版は、3.0系まではmingw64でしたが、3.1系からはucrt64に変更になりました。`ruby -v`と実行してプラットフォームがx64-mingw-ucrtになっている事が確認できるかと思います。

問題はこのucrt64版(x64-mingw-ucrt)です。Bundlerは`platform`でmingwやmswin等を指定できます。しかし、この機能はucrt64には対応していません。x64_mingwと指定しても、これはmingw64版の指定であって、同じくMingw-w64 GCCを用いていると言っても、ucrt64版は対象では無いと判断されます。現在の所、Bundlerにucrt64版を指定する`platform`に渡すオプションは存在しません。

ここでRalisに関わる問題が発生します。Railsはタイムゾーン情報を時刻を扱うためにtzinfoというgemを使います。このtzinfoをWindowsで使用する場合、Linuxとは違ってOSにタイムゾーンの情報のファイルが存在しないため、tzinfo-dataという別のgemが必要になります。そのため、Railsで生成されるGemfileでは、`platform`でWindows環境になるプラットフォームを指定してtzinfo-dataが使用するようにしています。しかし、この`platform`の指定ではucrt64版は対象とはならないため、tzinfo-dataが読み込まれず、railsの実行に失敗する状況になっていました。

根本的に修正されるにはBundler側がucrt64版に対応することとRails側がucrt64版でもtzinfo-dataを対象とするように初期のGemfileを用意するようにすることの二つが必要です。どちらにもissuesにすらあがっていないようですので、対応にはしばらくかかると思われます。

---

Bundler側とRalis側で対応されるまでは時間がかかりますので、それ以外の解決方法を三つほど紹介します。

#### Gemfileでtzinfo-dataを読み込むようにする。

ucrt64版であっても、Gemfileでtzinfo-dataを読む込むようにすれば良いとなります。まずは、下記のようなtemplate.rbを用意します。

```
data = File.read('Gemfile')
data.sub!(/^.*gem "tzinfo-data".*$/, 'install_if(-> { RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mingw|mswin|java/ }) { gem "tzinfo-data" }')
File.write('Gemfile', data)
```

そして`rais new アプリ名 -m template.rb`として作成すれば、エラー無く完了できるはずです。

どうしてこれでうまくいくかは、エラーになるときとのGemfileと比べてみることでわかるはずです。

#### ucrt64版以外のRubyを使う。

例えば、32bit版はmingw32であるためこの問題は起きません。また、MSYS2でもRubyのパッケージが存在し、mingw64版Rubyを使うという方法もあるでしょう。

#### 3.0系のRubyを使う。

3.0系まではmingw64版ですので、問題は起きません。

#### Linux環境にする。

Linux環境であればtzinfo-dataそのものが不要になり、問題になることはありません。Windowsの環境であればWSLを用いたり、Hyper-VやVirtualBox等の仮想環境でLinuxを用意すると良いでしょう。

他にも、Ruby 3.0系を使うという方法もあります。どうしても3.1系を使いたく、そして、なるべくこのようなエラーになるべく出くわしたくないという場合は、WSL上でアプリケーションを作成・開発すると良いでしょう。